# Elan touchpad: Kernel Config

Tags: kernel, gentoo, touchpad

I'm running Gentoo Linux on an Acer Chromebook 15 (CB5-571 `auron_yuna`) and I have a minimal kernel configured supporting everything I need except for my Elantech touchpad. I've read a bunch if other Stack exchange answers which suggest `i8042.{nopnp,nmux,noloop,reset}`, and using those the `AUX` port (where the touchpad is found) is discovered (as seen in the dmesg at http://pasted.co/478bf881), but the touchpad itself is not recognized. Since I have heavily modded the kernel (such that required firmware is built in and no modules are used and it only builds to a 6.9M initramfsless executable) I assume that I a missing some piece of kernel config (http://pasted.co/00aad1c3) which adds support to it. What config am I missing? Everything touchpad-related among `CONFIG_*ELAN*` is selected, and so is most of the `CROS` and `CHROME` stuff (`CROS_LPC` did not seem to work and spewed out a 'cannot find EC ID' error or something). What am I missing?

Comment: Is there relevant information in `/proc/bus/input/devices`? Anyway try selecting all `CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_*` options.

Comment: @jimmij the touchpad does not appear in `/proc/bus/input/devices `, but the keyboard (running through the same `i8042` port) does. I will test the `DESIGNWARE` config, which was completely disabled (`I2C_DESIGNWARE_CORE=n`).

Answer (score 1):

@jimmij solved it, suggesting enabling `CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_*`. My whole kernel config (for reference) can be found here: http://pasted.co/1f8d4965

Comment: Good. If you want to keep your kernel config minimal you can (most probably) unselect `CONFIG_I2C_DESIGNWARE_PCI`. Crucial ones are `*_CORE` and `*_PLATFORM`.

Comment: @jimmij Thanks! I'm actually working on minimizing my config now, so that helps.